Is it possible to return reference to hidden vector
I have something which looks similar to this (simplified it)
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    pub add_and_return_last_two: Box<dyn FnMut(&[u32]) -> &'a [u32] + 'a>,
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut vec = vec![0u32, 2u32];
        Self {
            add_and_return_last_two: Box::new(move |add| {
                vec.extend_from_slice(add);
                let len = vec.len();
                &vec[len - 2..len]
            }),
        }
    }
}

I get this error
captured variable cannot escape FnMut closure body FnMut closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing... ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape

How can I expose a "part" of the vector which lives long as MyStruct, feels unnecessary to wrap it in Box since I'm ok with it dying with MyStruct

No FnMut cannot return something with a lifetime tied to itself, it is simply not designed for it. Though its hard to know what to suggest since its unclear when and how add_and_return_last_two would be called and why it is dynamic instead of just a method.

i believe the problem is the fact that the closure inside MyStruct is capturing the vector and trying to return a reference to it at the same time without any borrowing which i don't think that's how rust works.
